# Problem on implementing multiple button with different actions inside a single cell in AG Grid Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can anyone help me out to implement multiple button with different actions inside a single cell in AG Grid Angular

i have tried out single button or link with action .. it worked fine for me .. but the problem is how to implement multiple button in a single grid.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the row element data we are using this below method in html

> `(rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"`

For a single cell let say 'Action',we can use cellRenderer and create external function for that and we can call it like below for example

```
{
        headerName: 'Action',
        cellRenderer: columnDefsProductActionRender
},
```

...
In this below function we will use multiple button or icon with data action attribute

```
function columnDefsProductActionRender(params) {
  if (params.value === undefined || params.value === null) {
    return '';
  } else {
    return `<a>
              <i class="fa fa-file-pen fa-icon"  data-action-type="edit" title="Edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>&nbsp;
            <a>
              <i class="fa fa-trash fa-icon fa-danger"  data-action-type="delete" title="delete" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>`;
  }
}
```

and try to get using getAttribute function in onRowClicked.After finding the exact action we can create our customized function in that.

```
public onRowClicked(e) {

    if (e.event.target !== undefined) {
      let data = e.data;
      let actionType = e.event.target.getAttribute('data-action-type');
      switch (actionType) {
        case 'Edit':
          return this.someAction1(data);
        case 'Delete':
          return this.someAction2(data);
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope this will work for you.